# Treeview save document on node selection

Tags: c#, winforms, save, treeview

I have a TextBox and a TreeView on my form, the treeview is showing a directory which holds multiple text files. when a node is selected, the text document is shown in the TextBox. I'm trying to save the work in the textbox before a different node is selected. I know I can get my file path for the selected node with the following code:

`TreeNode CurrentNode = e.Node;
 string fullpath = CurrentNode.FullPath;`

I believe I can use the BeforeSelect Event on the treeview to save it when I click on a different node. I just don't know how I would save the file without opening a saveDialog.

Comment: U can try `TreeView.AfterSelect` event, but occurs only when node is `checked` not when `unchecked`. For more info [AfterSelect Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In your form keep track of the currently selected `TreeNode` and the previously selected `TreeNode`:

```
TreeNode _priorNode, _currentNode;
```

It is the previously selected node's `FullPath` that you want to access to save the changes when someone changed the selection in the `TreeView`. When the user changes the selection, the `AfterSelect` event fires. In this event you can check for a previously select node and save the changes in the `TextBox`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // form level variables to hold current node and prior node
    TreeNode _priorNode, _currentNode;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // stores the prior node (based on current node) after node select    
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        String textToSave;
        String fileName;
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer;

        if (_currentNode != null)
        {
            _priorNode = _currentNode;
        }
        _currentNode = e.Node;
        if (_priorNode != null)
        {
            textToSave = textBox1.Text;
            fileName = _priorNode.FullPath;
            writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName);
            writer.Write(textToSave);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an unassigned variable error under if(_currentNode != null) and if(_priorNode != null)